# Compare types in base class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a `Part` base class

```
class Part {
    public PartType Type { get; set; }
}
```

with many implementations.

```
class Wire : Part {   }
```

I have a TreeView in my program. And when I click on an element of it, I want a list to be filled with all the Parts of the Type I clicked in the TreeView.

When I have multiple lists open I want only those be loading the parts that have the same PartType as I clicked in the TreeView.

```
class BasePartListViewModel<T> : ListViewModel where T : Part {
    protected override void OnTreeSelectionChanged(PartType type)
        if (type == PartType.Wire) {
            //load the Wires from the DB and display them
        } 
        else {
            //ignore the changed type event
        }
    }
}
```

But since this is a base class for all Parts by using  `T` I would like to replace

```
if (_type == PartTypeEnum.Wire)
```

with something like

```
if (_type == T.Type)
```

but that does of course not work. How else?

Comment: What is `_type`? How it is declared?

Comment: It is `PartType _type`. An Enum.

Comment: This isn't very possible.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: He wants an enum value.

Comment: `PartType` is an Enum I defined. Using `typeof(T)` does not return my Enum

Comment: Abstractions (=your base class) should not depend on details. Details should depend on abstractions. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

Comment: `SomeMethod` is actually an event handling method. And I just want to skip the hadling if the event was fired from a different type of Part.

Comment: Do you have any instance of `T` in the `BasePartListViewModel` class? If so, you may want to get its `PartType` and save it to use in the `SomeMethod`.

Comment: @Dmitry: No, I just updated the post with the real method name.

Comment: Can you modify the `Part` class in order to add attribute to it?

Comment: @Dmitry: Yes, if it is an additional property and not a big change to the existing code.

Comment: @Default: Updated the post.

Comment: What is the problem of using some kind of polymorphism `void OnTree(T type) { type.DoSomething(); }`

Comment: @RoyalBg: But I do not want `type` to do something. I want the DB to load the parts of the specified type and display it in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the part type is a static information for a class type by design (*am I right?*), you could use an attribute to store it:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class PartTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public readonly PartType PartType;

    public PartTypeAttribute(PartType partType)
    {
        PartType = partType;
    }
}
```

Then apply it to the descendant classes:

```
[PartType(PartType.Wire)]
class Wire : Part
{
}
```

Then in the static constructor of the `BasePartListViewModel` class you can obtian the corresponding value:

```
class BasePartListViewModel<T> : ListViewModel
    where T : Part
{
    private static PartType PartTypeOfT;

    static BasePartListViewModel()
    {
        var attr = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PartTypeAttribute), true)
            .FirstOrDefault() as PartTypeAttribute;
        if (attr != null)
            PartTypeOfT = attr.PartType;
    }

    protected override void OnTreeSelectionChanged(PartType type)
    {
        if (type == PartTypeOfT) {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a possibility. I'll check it.

Answer (score -2):

If you do this.GetType() it will return as BasePartListViewModel`1[Wire]

You should not be ideally referring this in the base class.

Comment: Two other answers talking about GetType have already been deleted. This question does not have anything to do with `System.Type` - it has to do with a custom `PartType` property that happens to have the name of `Type`.